# Is it the term "telescope" the same as a "detector"?

Tags: terminology, telescopes, particle-detectors

For example, in this reference, [MITO: muon telescope](https://www.swsc-journal.org/articles/swsc/full_html/2021/01/swsc200055/swsc200055.html) they use the term telescope but clearly the "telescope" is a muon detection system. And they also talk about angular resolution, angular aperture, etc. So my question is focused in, is the term telescope the same as a particle detector? and if a particle detector can be described by the properties of an optical-telescope(talking about optical geometry, diffraction, angular resolution, ect.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the sense of definition 2 of [wesbster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telescope)

> any of various tubular magnifying optical instruments

where  the detector  is used to record rays,(instead of the eye or film) directional vectors, composed of particles (muons in this case)

Comment: I don't think the Webster definition is really useful here. The MITO is neither tubular nor optical, and magnifying is not so easy to define here.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen note I say "in a sense", and explain with using the muons as optics uses rays.

Comment: Yes, I agree and I did not mean to criticise your explanation. Just that the quote from the Webster dictionary is perhaps a bit hard to match to this instrument.

Answer (score 1):

A particle detector is not necessarily a telescope, although in a specific context the terms could be interchangeable. It is like word *engine* used by firemen or word *pot* used by parents of a small child - the word is rather general, but no one is confused about its specific meaning. The technical term in speech theory is [*implicature*.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature)